# Laravel csrf_token(); view vs. controller?

Tags: laravel-4, csrf

This might seem like a silly question, but most of the documentation shows the csrf_token being echoed in the view. Is there any difference between doing that vs. generating the token in say a controller and then passing that token to a view?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any difference between doing that vs. generating the token in
>   say a controller and then passing that token to a view?

All that you are doing is creating an extra step for no reason. Laravel handles the token generation and session side of things.

The csrf_token is automatically included if you use `Form::open()`, so you dont need to echo it out yourself.

Comment: I'm doing HTML manipulation with a form component which is why it's a requirement in the controller.

Comment: What do you mean "a requirement in the controller"? What are you actually trying to do? Laravel handles CSRF if you set a filter in your routes. It shouldnt matter what you are doing in your controller...

Comment: You're right, it could take place in a closure, but it's neater for me to keep my code out of the routes file. I'm grabbing HTML from a database, pulling in some other data, dynamically updating the page to be rendered, and then outputting the full HTML as a string to my view. I guess you can implement the same code in the view with str_replace and whatnot, but that's not how I code. Can you inject Form::open() into the middle of a string variable?

Comment: I didnt say anything about a closure. At the end of the day, if you want the CSRF token, just include it in your string function with Form::token()